# Using results from parent queries in nested select

Tags: mysql, innodb, subquery

I'm sure this is a fairly trivial problem, but I'm not sure what to google to find the solution.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `transactions` (
  `name` text collate utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  `value` decimal(65,2) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

I populate this by cutting and pasting data from my internet banking service. 
Value can be a negative or positive value, what both date and name contain should be fairly obvious ;)
I have constructed a query to let me see my bottom line for each month:

```
SELECT sum(`value`) as 'change', DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%M %Y') as 'month'
FROM `transactions` 
WHERE 1
GROUP BY year(`date`), month(`date`)
```

Now I would like to add the total accumulated money in the account at the end of the month as an additional column.

```
SELECT sum(`value`) as 'change', DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%M %Y') as 'month', 
(SELECT sum(`value`) FROM `transactions` WHERE `date` <= 123) as 'accumulated'
FROM `transactions` 
WHERE 1
GROUP BY year(`date`), month(`date`)
```

123 is not exactly what I want in there, but I do not understand how to get at the result from my DATE_FORMAT inside that subquery.

Is this even the proper way to approach the problem?

This is mostly a personal exercise (running on a very small dataset) so I'm not very concerned about performance, readable SQL is far more important.

I am running a InnoDB table on MySQL 5.0.45

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  change,
        CONCAT(mymonth, ' ', myyear) AS 'month',
        (
        SELECT  SUM(`value`)
        FROM    `transactions`
        WHERE   `date` < DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01.', mymonth, '.', myyear, '%D.%M.%Y'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
        )
FROM    (
        SELECT  sum(`value`) as 'change', YEAR(date) AS myyear, MONTH(date) AS mymonth
        FROM    `transactions` 
        WHERE 1
        GROUP BY 
                YEAR(`date`), MONTH(`date`)
        ) q
```

You wrote that you don't cate for performance, but this syntax is not much more complex but will be more efficient (just in case):

```
SELECT  SUM(value) AS change,
        CONCAT(MONTH(`date`), ' ', YEAR(`date`)) AS 'month',
        @r : = @r + SUM(value) AS cumulative
FROM    (
        SELECT  @r := 0
        ) AS vars,
        transactions
WHERE 1
GROUP BY 
        YEAR(`date`), MONTH(`date`)
ORDER BY
        YEAR(`date`), MONTH(`date`)
```

This one will count cumulative `SUM`'s as well, but it will count each month only once.

Comment: I *think* I understand what's going on here, but what is that first "change" field?

Comment: It's your SUM from the inner subquery. Sorry, I didn't notice it's once table, see the post update